# Use the path listed in a text file to get the files data in python

Tags: python, text, python-requests, telegram

Currently, my script is working. It can extract data but with an absolute path only, I need to modify it to make it universal when it comes to getting the path.

I have a plan to modify my script that can simply add the path of the files into the .txt file and the script will read it as a directory to get the file and extract its content, but I need help to figure out what I need to use on my script to make it work, is there someone can help me?

```
import requests

path = "/home/admin/files/myfiles.txt"
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    line = f.read().rstrip()
    print(line)
```

**myfiles.txt** contains directories

```
/home/admin/files/test1.txt
/home/admin/files/test2.txt
/home/admin/files/test3.txt
```

these directory are path of the files that I need to extract the data once I execute the python file it will extract data on the file listed **(test1,test2,test3.txt)** and send it to telegram as text.

Currently, this is the modified script that can read the path.

If you need more details let me know.

Comment: Does the file contain absolute paths and what did you mean by saying "make it centralized"?

Comment: what means `"make it centralized"` ?

Comment: maybe first use `sys.argv[1]` to run it as `python script.py /home/admin/files/myfiles.txt`

Comment: if you want to read file from folder where you keep script then you have to get path to this folder `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and later create `path = os.path.join(BASE, "myfiles.txt")`

Comment: @rodskies, you changed the word `centralized` with `universal` but it still does not answer my question.

Comment: Hi @ArtyomVancyan, yes it contains path of the files and my plan is when I add a multiple file path in the .txt file the python script will read it as directory and get the file.

Answer (score 0):

> it contains path of the files and my plan is when I add a multiple file path in the .txt file the python script will read it as directory and get the file.

If I get you right you are looking for `readlines` method to read the list of files' paths.

```py
path = "/home/admin/files/myfiles.txt"

with open(path, 'r') as fp:
    filepaths = fp.readlines()

for filepath in filepaths:
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        # do something with file
        content = file.read()
```